# Как добавить ClanLib в cmakelist при использовании библиотеки

Tags: linux, c++11, cmake

установил библиотеку ClanLib-3.0 на ubuntu, не знаю как в cmake прописать, через командную строку компилится

Comment: Если установили пакет, то зачем компилировать? Или поставили пакет исходников?

Comment: @alexis031182 из исходников командами **configure**, **make**, **make install**. Проблема в том, как её использовать в своих программах, использующие cmake для компиляции

Comment: Вы тогда уточните это в вопросе, поскольку иначе неочевидно.